# How To add a link for image1 and image2

Tags: javascript

```js
function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}

function displayPreviousImage() {
    x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
}

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
}

var images = [], x = -1;
images[0] = "image1.png";
images[1] = "image2.png";
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
   </body>
</html>
```

> I have two images: image1 and image2 - which will change automatically.
>   5 seconds from now I need to attach a link for both images i.e for
>   image1 and image2. Please help me with this

Comment: what is your link url?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. You should perhaps start the timer at the end of your script section: `window.onLoad = startTimer();` , instead of `<body onload="...`

Comment: You can create a new array, have the first array to = the link for the first image, second array for the second image. Add array[x] for the links and have it display or whatever it is you wish to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but this is very simple, a good starting point for you to make improvements. 
I'm not sure what you want the link to do so it's up to you to work out the rest unless you get give more information on what it is you want this link to display as and what you want it to do...

If you don't understand what I have done/added then please read my comment post in your question.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
            document.getElementById("Links").innerHTML=links[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
            document.getElementById("Links").innerHTML=links[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IehB7.png";
images[1] = "http://untroubled.org/backgrounds/space/stars.gif";
        var links = [];
        links[0]="Link One";
        links[1]="Link Two";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
     <span id="Links"></span>
          </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>change picture</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a id="img-link" href="startpicture.jpg">
      <img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
    </a>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
      var images = ["img.png", "img.bmp"], x = -1;
      var imageElem = document.getElementById("img");
      var imageAnchor = document.getElementById("img-link");
      function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        var imagePath = images[x];
        imageElem.src = imagePath;
        imageAnchor.href = imagePath;
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
        x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
        var imagePath = images[x];
        imageElem.src = imagePath;
        imageAnchor.href = imagePath;
      }

      function startTimer() {
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
      }
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
        startTimer();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice, I thought about posting a method like this but i'm not sure if this "link" is the image link or a link to a page. I like your clean up on the Javascript, I got lazy.

Comment: Ah, I might get to misreadings. I'll remove my post soon after his question takes shape. Thanks for your notice!